# Add startup/shutdown handlers to FastAPI app with lifespan API

Tags: python, fastapi, lifecycle, starlette

Consider a FastAPI using the `lifespan` parameter like this:

```py
def lifespan(app):
    print('lifespan start')
    yield
    print('lifespan end')


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
```

Now I want to register a sub app with its own lifecycle functions:

```py
app.mount(mount_path, sub_app)
```

**How can I register startup/shutdown handlers for the sub app?**

All solutions I could find either require control over the `lifespan` generator (which I don't have) or involve deprecated methods like `add_event_handler` (which doesn't work when `lifespan` is set).

---

**Update** Minimal reproducible example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

# --- main app ---

def lifespan(_):
    print("startup")
    yield
    print("shutdown")

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

# --- sub app ---

sub_app = FastAPI()

@sub_app.get("/")
async def sub_root():
    return {"message": "Hello Sub World"}

app.mount("/sub", sub_app)
app.on_event("startup")(lambda: print("sub startup"))    # doesn't work
app.on_event("shutdown")(lambda: print("sub shutdown"))  # doesn't work
```

Run with: `uvicorn my_app:app --port 8000`

Comment: @Chris Fair enough. I updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure if I like it... It accesses the existing lifespan generator via `app.router.lifespan_context` and wraps it with additional startup/shutdown commands:

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

...

main_app_lifespan = app.router.lifespan_context

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan_wrapper(app):
    print("sub startup")
    async with main_app_lifespan(app) as maybe_state:
        yield maybe_state
    print("sub shutdown")

app.router.lifespan_context = lifespan_wrapper
```

Output:

```
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
sub startup
startup
INFO:     Application startup complete.
...
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
shutdown
sub shutdown
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
```

Comment: Exactly, also AFTER app is started - you can't actually add additional shutdown events, so this FastAPI decision is *strange* at least.